# How to change status based on date in another text box on form - Access

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

Im making a training database.

Im looking to change a textbox value on a form based on a date in another textbox.

I have the following:

```
Refresher Period - TxtRef
Participation Date - TxtPart
Refresher Date - TxtRefDate
Status - TxtStatus
```

I want status to update to either - `In Date`, `Expired` or `Expiring` based on the following rules applying to the date in `TxtRefDate`.

> Value < Now() + 60 "Expiring"
>
> Value < Now() "Expired"
>
> Value > Now() + 60 "In Date"

Comment: What's the name of the Textbox you want to change ? TxtRefDate is the source for date, right ?

Comment: Yeah taking a refresher date from TxtRefDate and putting it in TxtStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a small helper function:

```
Public Function Status(ByVal RefDate As Date) As String

    Dim Description As String

    Select Case DateDiff("d", Date, RefDate)
        Case > 60
            Description = "In date"
        Case > 0
            Description = "Expiring"
        Case Else
            Description = "Expired"
    End Select

    Status = Description

End Function
```

Now, set the *ControlSource* of *txtStatus* to:

```
=Status([TxtRefDate])
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, where would I add the helper function? Just within the object for that form?

Comment: Got this to work! Thanks a lot. Had to change Status to StatusType as it was clashing with an object on my form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like that ?

```
If TxtRefDate.Value < Now() Then
    TxtStatus.Value = "Expired"
Else:
    If TxtRefDate.Value < Now() + 60 Then
        TxtStatus.Value = "Expiring"
    Else:
        TxtStatus.Value = "In Date"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Thryn, This doesnt appear to work. Does it matter that the TxtRefDate box is auto filled with the following:

Private Sub TxtPart_AfterUpdate()
Me.TxtRef.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", TxtRefPer, TxtPart)
End Sub